# Is there an explode function in angularjs as PHP does?

Tags: angularjs

In php when you want to explode a variable value just used the explode function:

```
$day = date("j", $exploded_line[0]);
```

In angularjs. I want to explode the date. I have `$scope.from`.

```
$scope.from = "2015-01-10";
```

I want to get only the day which is 10. Is there a explode function in angularjs? Thank you  in advance.

Comment: I think you're searching for string split from javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 1):

You can use split function of js string.

```
  var string = "a;b;c;d;e";
  var splittedStringArray = string.split(";");
```

->  ['a','b','c','d','e']

Answer (score 0):

You can use in angular like below,

```
$scope.beforesplit='9,10,11,12'
$scope.aftersplit= $scope.beforesplit.split(',');
```

$scope.aftersplit have ["9", "10", "11", "12"]

Hope it helps!